# How to cancel Notification once set?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I've set a notification this way:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    CharSequence from = bundle.getString("alarm_title");
    CharSequence message = bundle.getString("alarm_text");
    int notify_id = bundle.getInt("notify_id");

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, AppActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notifyIntent, 0);

    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_menu_glases, "App Information", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    nm.notify(notify_id, notif);
```

}

Everything works fine and I'm happy with it. Now I'd like to `cancel` the notification by ID.

My **1st try** failed (alarm still coming up):

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(), notifyID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
if(pendingIntent != null) {
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    pendingIntent.cancel();  
}
```

And **2nd try** failed too:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.cancel(notify_id);
```

Anybody got an idea of how to stop the notification once set? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
nMgr.cancel(notify_id);
```

In your code i changed `notifyID` to `notify_id`. The notification id should be the same as one used while creating the notification. Just check that and it should work fine as mentioned in the [api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29).

Comment: my fault - notifyID is set with the same value. missed to copy it :) that's not the bug *updated my question*

Comment: Just try logging the id before creating the notification and before cancelling it. Just check if they are the same or not, because your 2nd approach is totally correct.

Comment: that's a good point - I'll give it a try. **EDIT** found the bug. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```